# How to convert between UTF-8 and native String in Java?

Tags: java, utf-8, converters, native

[image]

Just like the picture, I'd like to convert between the encoded UTF-8 String and Native String in Java. 
Would anyone some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

ps.
For example,

```
String a = "&#x8FD9;&#x662F;&#x4E00;&#x4E2A;&#x4F8B;&#x5B50;,this is a example";
String b = null;
// block A: processing a, and let b = "这是一个例子,this is a example"
```

How to implement the "block A"?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please learn http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show what have you tired so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(...)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml(java.lang.String)) is what you want.  Depending on where your original string came from, one of the HTML variants may be more appropriate.

Use like so:

```
String a = "&#x8FD9;&#x662F;&#x4E00;&#x4E2A;&#x4F8B;&#x5B50;,this is a example";
String b = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(a);
// block A: processing a, and let b = "这是一个例子,this is a example"
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

Output:

```
&#x8FD9;&#x662F;&#x4E00;&#x4E2A;&#x4F8B;&#x5B50;,this is a example
这是一个例子,this is a example
```

There are methods for converting the other way also.

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thanks for your advice on question description.

Comment: @HuXiaoxiang - no problems at all.  If this answer helped, please consider making this the accepted answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Charset. See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(text)
```

---

Or

you can also use `getBytes()` method of 'java.lang.String' Class

```
text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

*documentation:*

> **public byte[] getBytes(Charset charset)**
>   Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the given charset,
>   storing the result into a
>   new byte array.
>
> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character
>   sequences with this charset's default replacement byte array. The
>   CharsetEncoder class should be used when more control over the
>   encoding process is required.
>
> ***Parameters:***   charset - The Charset to be used to encode the String
>
> ***Returns:***   The resultant byte array
>
> ***Since:***
>   1.6

Answer (score 0):

To the right are hexadecimal numeric HTML entities.

Now the apache commons library has a StringEscapeUtils which can convert *from* that to String, but the reverse is not obvious (= should be tried, might give named entities).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String a = "&#x8FD9;&#x662F;&#x4E00;&#x4E2A;&#x4F8B;&#x5B50;,this is a example";
    String b = fromHtmlEntities(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    String a2 = toHtmlEntities(b);
    System.out.println(a2.equals(a));
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(a2);
}

public static String fromHtmlEntities(String s) {
    Pattern numericEntityPattern = Pattern.compile("\\&#[Xx]([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,6});");
    Matcher m = numericEntityPattern.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16);
        String replacement = new String(new int[] { codePoint }, 0, 1);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

// Uses java 8  
public static String toHtmlEntities(String s) {
    int[] codePoints = s.codePoints().flatMap(
            (cp) -> cp < 128 // ASCII?
            ? IntStream.of(cp)
            : String.format("&#x%X;", cp).codePoints())
        .toArray();
    return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I have the same thinking way to solve the problem, but you can give it right away, really appreciate!

Comment: Mmm, maybe check for other Chinese, that those entities are `int` code points and not UTF-16 `char`s: `` as either `&#x24F5C;` (fine) or `&#xD853;&#xDF5C;`.